Proof of $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+2 b}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{b+2 c}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{c+2 a}}<\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$
So I was searching for proof of this inequality at two different threads (Proving inequality $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a+2b}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{b+2c}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{c+2a}}\lt \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$ and Convicted of squares in an Inequality and my Weakness)
User called Micheal Rosenberg had posted two slightly different proofs. One of them ends with $\sum_{\text {sym }} 2 a^4 b c+2 a^3 b^3+24 a^3 b^2 c+12.5 a^2 b^2 c^2 \geq 0$ while the other $\sum_{\text {cyc }} 4 a^3 b^3+4 a^4 b c+24 a^3 b^2 c+24 a^3 c^2 b+25 a^2 b^2 c^2 > 0$. These two inequalities are not the same so at least one of them is definitely false but no one corrected on either of comments.
I guess proof with strictly greater is correct.
Also I don't understand how $\sum_{c y c} \frac{a}{(a+2 b)(a+2 c)} \leq \frac{3}{2(a+b+c)}$ implies $\sum_{\text {cyc }} 4 a^3 b^3+4 a^4 b c+24 a^3 b^2 c+24 a^3 c^2 b+25 a^2 b^2 c^2 >0$

After "full expanding" by a talented person or machine...

Both seem correct to me, except there cannot be equality (which doesn't mean the first statement is wrong).  If you are worried about the terms not matching, convert both into either symmetric sums or cyclic sums, they will appear the same.
